# IPHONE: I have this line on my instruments... should I worry?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have this line (see picture) in my instruments while analyzing objects allocation.
The line says 1.17 Gbytes of overall bytes??? what does it means? Should I worry?
[image: should I worry?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no, that is the cumulative memory of total allocations... but it does seem very high (I ran my biggest app and couldnt get it over 140MB). It would suggest that you are creating and destroying (or leaking) an excessive amount of objects/memory.

I would recommend two things:

1) click the (i) button next to ObjectAlloc (top left) and turn on "Only track active allocations", and under allocation lifespan below choose "Created & Still Living", then rerun your tests. This will allow you to track the current memory footprint of your app.

2) perform some optimisation of any loops with memory allocation (object creation), and run a thorough leak test using a tethered device (I believe there is issues with leak testing and the simulator).

Comment: thanks for the answer... when I track just the active allocations the number falls to 2.10 MB with peaks at 13 MB when it is doing something memory intensive. It is reporting no leaks or memory warnings. After using the app for 5 minutes it crashes 1 out of 5 times. I could not identify what it is. No clue on terminal. Just appears to be memory related.

Comment: Check the dump message when it crashes, post it here even.
Also search google for debugging with xcode, there are lots of resources available, particularly NSZombie if you think you are having dealloc problems.

Comment: thanks. That's it. My application was creating and destroying too much objects. The problem was solved.